# Yii2: How should site-wide search work?

Tags: search, yii2

What is the best practice methododology of implementing site-wide search in Yii2?

This question is not about *how* to implement search specifically, but rather about what kind of approach to use. Should we use Sphinx? Elasticsearch? Or do we use UNION selects to get the data into a DataProvider?

Assume the application is using a relational database to store data. We want to search and display *multiple* different models. For example, our database contains tables of Books, Authors and Stores. When we search for a *keyword* we want to display results from all 3 tables (matching Books by title or content, Authors by full name and Stores by name etc).

There are [tutorials](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/searching-with-elasticsearch-yii2/) which show how to use Elasticsearch but assume that our data is stored in the Elasticsearch database, which does not make sense. Our data is already stored in MySQL or PostgreSQL. Does this mean 
we need to maintain a duplicate of our data in the Elasticsearch database?

Comment: Did you find the best approach for this? Im looking forward to see what is your experience

Comment: @farrusete There's no single "right way" it seems. I found some ways to sync MySQL with Elasticsearch (namely [jdbc](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc) and [river](https://github.com/scharron/elasticsearch-river-mysql)) but it looks very complex so I never tried it myself.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best practice methododology of implementing site-wide search in Yii2?

That depends on many factors, so I cant give you a specific recommendation for your case. Some of the factors to think about are:

1. What would you like to achieve with this search? Is every little bit in your database a significant search term?
2. Do you need only full-text-search or a wide range of analytics?
3. Have you any limits in time or costs?
4. Can your (tech-)infrastructure handle your ideas?
5. Is it worth to bring in another extensive technology in the project?
6. Can you handle additional maintenance tasks to run such a search engine?
7. And many more ...

---

In my internal Yii2 Project with a **PostgreSQL** RDBMS, I decided to use a PostgreSQL Text Search Type called [tsvector](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-textsearch.html). Thats good enough for my needs. Why?

1. You can use [Stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming).
2. Supports Fuzzy search.
3. Supports basic ranking.
4. Supports multiple languages.

I highly recommend this blog post [Postgres full-text search is Good Enough](http://rachbelaid.com/postgres-full-text-search-is-good-enough/).